# © not handle correctly by a verbatim

Tags: symbols, verbatim

Is there a reason why the following verbatim section doesn't work as expected:

```
\begin{verbatim}
© copyright blahblah .....
\end{verbatim}
```

In fact I get: **Âl’ copyright blah blah**

Instead of the nice **©**.

I will use the **(c)** notation, but anyway if you have a better solution, it will be welcome.

---

Full MWE demonstrating problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
© copyright blahblah .....
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fontenc` package deals with font encodings in the output file (pdf generally). But the font encodings in the input file are handled by `inputenc` package. Adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        %%<---- add this
\begin{document}
  \begin{verbatim}
     © copyright blahblah .....
  \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Bonus**
 <sub>There is a special offer for now ;)</sub>

To get rid of the warnings regarding font substitutions (and have some aesthetic looks), you may prefer to use some font like `libertine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
  \begin{verbatim}
     © copyright blahblah .....
  \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A relevant post on the importance of that character encoding, and why the copyright symbol wasn't working without it: [There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text](http://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/). Or the article that's distilling, [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).